# Android offline voice recognition with simple commands/vocabulary

Tags: android, voice-recognition, cmusphinx

I am looking for some library that would allow me to create an offline voice recognition inside my Android app. There will be **simple vocabulary consisting of up to 15 short (one word) commands** for my app. Response time is crucial in my case.

Is there any viable offline option (free & paid)? I am aware of offline version of Sphinx but will it be the option with fastest response (again, I only need my app to recognize few commands not the whole speech-to-text functionality)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had success using PocketSphinx for this type of application. I'd suggest building the [PocketSphinx Demo](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/) app, use the online sphinx [lmtool](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool-new.html) to build language model of your short list of commands and see if it meets your response time needs. If the `onResults` callback isn't fast enough, you can use the `onPartialResults` callback which returns almost immediately--that's what I do and I'm happy with the performance. The demo app has a little built-in timer in the UI, too.

If you use the online [lmtool](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool-new.html), you can just take the `lm` file and the `dict` file from what it produces, using those to replace the corresponding `lm` and `dict` files in the language model they point you to in the demo setup instructions.

It was a bit of a pain to get built, but it was my first time using the NDK, which was finicky.

Comment: It's also recommended to build a grammar in JSGF format instead of lmtool. See http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm for details

Comment: I like PocketShpinx but it feels not developed enough yet

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for keyword-spotting software? [sensoryinc.com](http://sensoryinc.com/) has been doing this for years, and only recently made some Android apps. Here is an example in which I'm driving and want to use a voice trigger to record an audio note. Only after I say "hello blue genie" does it start recording my audio note.
http://vimeo.com/64658273
(no I don't work for Sensory but I think their tech is greatly underappreciated)

Comment: seems like an online solution

Comment: No it's in airplane mode the entire time (you can see the little airplane icon in the top to the left of the green battery)

Comment: @Ben can't seem to find a way to download their SDK. Only videos are on the site!

Comment: Right, what you saw in the video was distributed to us at a conference - it's an app not an SDK. I'm sure they have one because some years ago I used it, but it's not freely available.