# using voice command in android how to navigate pages

Tags: android

i want to develop a application to navigate one page to another page using voice command

here is my code

```
 public class mainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

 ArrayList<String> StoredCommand = new ArrayList<String>();

private static final String TAG = "VoiceRecognition";

private static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

private static final Context View = null;

private ListView mList;

private Handler mHandler;

private Spinner mSupportedLanguageView;

/**
 * Called with the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mHandler = new Handler();

    StoredCommand.add("Path Recoder");
    StoredCommand.add("Path Selector");
    StoredCommand.add("Stop");
    StoredCommand.add("Pause");


    // Inflate our UI from its XML layout description.
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Get display items for later interaction
    Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);

    mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    mSupportedLanguageView = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.supported_languages);

    // Check to see if a recognition activity is present
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
            new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
    if (activities.size() != 0) {
        speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    } else {
        speakButton.setEnabled(false);
        speakButton.setText("Recognizer not present");
    }

    // Most of the applications do not have to handle the voice settings. If the application
    // does not require a recognition in a specific language (i.e., different from the system
    // locale), the application does not need to read the voice settings.
    refreshVoiceSettings();
}

/**
 * Handle the click on the start recognition button.
 */
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_speak) {
        startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
    }
}

/**
 * Fire an intent to start the speech recognition activity.
 */
private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

    // Specify the calling package to identify your application
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getClass().getPackage().getName());

    // Display an hint to the user about what he should say.
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech recognition demo");

    // Given an hint to the recognizer about what the user is going to say
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);

    // Specify how many results you want to receive. The results will be sorted
    // where the first result is the one with higher confidence.
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 5);

    // Specify the recognition language. This parameter has to be specified only if the
    // recognition has to be done in a specific language and not the default one (i.e., the
    // system locale). Most of the applications do not have to set this parameter.
    if (!mSupportedLanguageView.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Default")) {
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE,
                mSupportedLanguageView.getSelectedItem().toString());
    }

    startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
}

/**
 * Handle the results from the recognition activity.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it could have heard
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
               matches));

        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder()  ;
        for (String match:matches){


        switch(resultCode) {
        case RESULT_OK:
            Log.i(TAG, "RESULT_OK");

            if(StoredCommand==matches)
            {
                //Button next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);
                 if (matches.contains("Path Recoder"))
                {

                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(View, PahtRecoder.class);
                 startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

                 else if(matches.contains("path selector"))
                 {
                     Intent myIntent = new Intent(View, Pahtselector.class);
                     startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

                 }
                 else if(matches.contains("stop"))
                 {
                     Intent myIntent = new Intent(View, Pahtselector.class);
                     startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

                 }
                 else if(matches.contains("start"))

                 {

                     Intent myIntent = new Intent(View, Pahtselector.class);
                     startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                 }
                 }



            else
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "COMMAND_NOT_MATCHING");
            }


            break;
        case RESULT_CANCELED:
            Log.i(TAG, "RESULT_CANCELED");
            break;
        case RecognizerIntent.RESULT_AUDIO_ERROR:
            Log.i(TAG, "RESULT_AUDIO_ERROR");
            break;
        case RecognizerIntent.RESULT_CLIENT_ERROR:
            Log.i(TAG, "RESULT_CLIENT_ERROR");
            break;
        case RecognizerIntent.RESULT_NETWORK_ERROR:
            Log.i(TAG, "RESULT_NETWORK_ERROR");
            break;
        case RecognizerIntent.RESULT_NO_MATCH:
            Log.i(TAG, "RESULT_NO_MATCH");
            break;
        case RecognizerIntent.RESULT_SERVER_ERROR:
            Log.i(TAG, "RESULT_SERVER_ERROR");
            break;
        default:
            Log.i(TAG, "RESULT_UNKNOWN");
            break;
        }




        }

    }





    else{
        Log.e("TAG", "Recognition is Failed");
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void refreshVoiceSettings() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Sending broadcast");
    sendOrderedBroadcast(RecognizerIntent.getVoiceDetailsIntent(this), null,
            new SupportedLanguageBroadcastReceiver(), null, Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
}

private void updateSupportedLanguages(List<String> languages) {
    // We add "Default" at the beginning of the list to simulate default language.
    languages.add(0, "Default");

    SpinnerAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, languages.toArray(
                    new String[languages.size()]));
    mSupportedLanguageView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void updateLanguagePreference(String language) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.language_preference);
    textView.setText(language);
}

/**
 * Handles the response of the broadcast request about the recognizer supported languages.
 *
 * The receiver is required only if the application wants to do recognition in a specific
 * language.
 */
private class SupportedLanguageBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Receiving broadcast " + intent);

        final Bundle extra = getResultExtras(false);

        if (getResultCode() != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showToast("Error code:" + getResultCode());
                }
            });
        }

        if (extra == null) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showToast("No extra");
                }
            });
        }

        if (extra.containsKey(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES)) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateSupportedLanguages(extra.getStringArrayList(
                            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES));
                }
            });
        }

        if (extra.containsKey(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE)) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateLanguagePreference(
                            extra.getString(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String text) {

        Toast.makeText(mainActivity.this, text, 1000).show();
    }
}
```

according to the stored command i need to navigate those pages.but result is Google voice  option work but commands are not working.is there any wrong of my pattern matching...please give me solution for that.
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this out as a minimal implementation of `onActivityResult()`:

```
if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
{
    ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
    mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
               matches));
    for (String bestMatch:matches)
    {
        if (bestMatch.equalsIgnoreCase("Path Recoder"))
        {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(View, PahtRecoder.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        else if(bestMatch.equalsIgnoreCase("Path Selector"))
        {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(View, Pahtselector.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        else if(bestMatch.equalsIgnoreCase("Stop"))
        {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(View, Pahtselector.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        else if(bestMatch.equalsIgnoreCase("Pause"))
        {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(View, Pahtselector.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "COMMAND_NOT_MATCHING");
        }
    }
}
```

**Further Update:** My initial post was wrong - `StoredCommand` should not be used; on older speech recognition platforms they would be provided with a list of possible utterances and the engine would try to match what you say against the possibilities. However, the default engine on Android does not need this. By the way, what does your `mList` display?

Note also that I have not tested any of the code above...

Comment: when user says "path recoder" then it should be navigate to the path recoder page.that is what i want.i sored command in array list called StoredCommand.if you say so then tell me what should i do.can you edit this or give me solution.thank you

Comment: I've updated my answer, so please note `StoredCommand` is never used by the engine; the default Google Voice does not use input hints.

Comment: but using Google voice its hard to identify what we said.if we say "Stop" it's not generate stop word in list view.So cannot navigate to the page.so how i get correct word to the list view.

Comment: @KavindiWicramasingha That is a very good question! It would be nice if there was that more constrained mode available. [Pocket Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/) seems to be one option - here's a [similar question from two years ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396046/android-speech-recognition-without-using-google-server), so you could perhaps ask again to see if the state of the art has improved - [this non-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4396104/1270789) is what you are after, I think?

Comment: Sorry, another comment - here's [a promising question and answer from this April](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307373/android-offline-voice-recognition-with-simple-commands-vocabulary).

Comment: no its not working.when i say start the exception occure.i think my intent command is not work.it recognize the word but cannot navigate to the page.i think we should change the patten.My list display similar word i spoke.not the correct word but similar.

Comment: please any idea when i say stop it generate exception.thats mean my intent is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Hi all this is the code for navigate from one page to another page using voice command.It will useful any one

public class mainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

```
private static final String TAG = "VoiceRecognition";

private static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

private static final Context View = null;

private ListView mList;

private Handler mHandler;

private Spinner mSupportedLanguageView;

/**
 * Called with the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mHandler = new Handler();



    // Inflate our UI from its XML layout description.
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Get display items for later interaction
    Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);

    mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    mSupportedLanguageView = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.supported_languages);

    // Check to see if a recognition activity is present
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
            new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
    if (activities.size() != 0) {
        speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    } else {
        speakButton.setEnabled(false);
        speakButton.setText("Recognizer not present");
    }

    // Most of the applications do not have to handle the voice settings. If the application
    // does not require a recognition in a specific language (i.e., different from the system
    // locale), the application does not need to read the voice settings.
    refreshVoiceSettings();
}

/**
 * Handle the click on the start recognition button.
 */
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_speak) {
        startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
    }
}

/**
 * Fire an intent to start the speech recognition activity.
 */
private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

    // Specify the calling package to identify your application
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getClass().getPackage().getName());

    // Display an hint to the user about what he should say.
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech recognition demo");

    // Given an hint to the recognizer about what the user is going to say
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);

    // Specify how many results you want to receive. The results will be sorted
    // where the first result is the one with higher confidence.
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 5);

    // Specify the recognition language. This parameter has to be specified only if the
    // recognition has to be done in a specific language and not the default one (i.e., the
    // system locale). Most of the applications do not have to set this parameter.
    if (!mSupportedLanguageView.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Default")) {
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE,
                mSupportedLanguageView.getSelectedItem().toString());
    }

    startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
}

/**
 * Handle the results from the recognition activity.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it could have heard
         ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                    RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                       matches));
           for (String bestMatch : matches) {
                if (bestMatch.contains("record") || bestMatch.contains("cod") || bestMatch.contains("ed")) {
                    // Intent myIntent = new Intent(View, PahtRecoder.class);
                    // startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                    Intent my = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            PathRecorderStart.class);
                    startActivityForResult(my, 0);
                }

                else if (bestMatch.contains("select") || bestMatch.contains("elect") || bestMatch.contains("ct")) {
                    // Intent myIntent = new Intent(View, PahtRecoder.class);
                    // startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                    Intent my = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            PathSelectorOptions.class);
                    startActivityForResult(my, 0);
                }

                else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "COMMAND_NOT_MATCHING");
                }

            }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void refreshVoiceSettings() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Sending broadcast");
    sendOrderedBroadcast(RecognizerIntent.getVoiceDetailsIntent(this), null,
            new SupportedLanguageBroadcastReceiver(), null, Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
}

private void updateSupportedLanguages(List<String> languages) {
    // We add "Default" at the beginning of the list to simulate default language.
    languages.add(0, "Default");

    SpinnerAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, languages.toArray(
                    new String[languages.size()]));
    mSupportedLanguageView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void updateLanguagePreference(String language) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.language_preference);
    textView.setText(language);
}

/**
 * Handles the response of the broadcast request about the recognizer supported languages.
 *
 * The receiver is required only if the application wants to do recognition in a specific
 * language.
 */
private class SupportedLanguageBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Receiving broadcast " + intent);

        final Bundle extra = getResultExtras(false);

        if (getResultCode() != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showToast("Error code:" + getResultCode());
                }
            });
        }

        if (extra == null) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showToast("No extra");
                }
            });
        }

        if (extra.containsKey(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES)) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateSupportedLanguages(extra.getStringArrayList(
                            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES));
                }
            });
        }

        if (extra.containsKey(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE)) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateLanguagePreference(
                            extra.getString(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String text) {

        Toast.makeText(mainActivity.this, text, 1000).show();
    }
}

}
```