# How to control my app's button with voice commands OFFLINE (WITHOUT 3rd PARTY)

Tags: android, android-studio, arduino, voice-recognition

I designed an app for home automation. See the picture for the layout. I want to turn on light / fan with voice along with touching the buttons for it. My motive is that it will help blind people, so no clicks should be required after opening app. The blind user will use "Ok Google" feature to open the app and as soon as the app gets opened the user will just say "turn on light 1" and it makes to auto touch on light 1 button making the light 1 to turn ON.
Connect button asks user to turn on bluetooth(If not already ON) and makes the connection to arduino. If bluetooth is OFF then dialog opens and clicking allow turns bluetooth on.

**P.S**

I already designed the app and lights / fan are turning ON/OFF with their respective button.
I just want it to be voice controlled. **And I want it all OFFLINE**

[image: Layout Of The App]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Speech Recognition without using google server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396046/android-speech-recognition-without-using-google-server)

Comment: No it is not. I only need to use 5-6 voice commands so for that using 3rd party functionality is a bad idea for sure

Comment: The linked answer can work for you. Use PocketSphinx.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android offline voice recognition with simple commands/vocabulary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307373/android-offline-voice-recognition-with-simple-commands-vocabulary)